# Do there exist any spells or ritual things / chants in Old Norse, Old Irish, or Old English online in text format?

Tags: folklore, reference-request, magic, medieval-europe

I have found the voluspa and other large Old Norse texts. Then there's Beowulf. I've seen several Old Irish poems as well.

But what about spells and magic? Do there exist any of those online in the Original Language? For example, an Old Norse magic spell in the Old Norse language, in text format.

Comment: Here we go https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galdrab%C3%B3k

Comment: You could search by the book "Trolldom: spells and methods of the norse folk magic tradition" and maybe this one: "Asatru Book of Blotar and Rituals: By the Asatru Folk Assembly".